# unclean url displayed instead of rewrite - htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^rewrite-php-page/$ /example.com/rewrite-php-page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rewrite-php-page-([^-]*)-get-input-query-([^-]*)/$ /example.com/rewrite-php-page.php?firstquery=$1&get-input-query=$2&submit=Send+values [L]

Rewriterule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap-xml.php [L]

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 403 /error_pages/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.php
```

I'm trying to rewrite my site urls seo friendly. When I access my site url like this

http://www.example.com/rewrite-php-page/

This rewritten url also working fine when I directly access this url http://www.example.com/rewrite-php-page-123-get-input-query-456/ . But, when I submit a form with user inputs it doesn't redirect to this url

http://www.example.com/rewrite-php-page-123-get-input-query-456/

instead of this above url it normaly print the parameters in url like this

http://www.example.com/rewrite-php-page.php?firstquery=111&get-input-query=222&submit=Send+values

What should I do if I want to get the proper clean url when I'm submitting a form ?

Comment: `get-input-query-456` is not more "clean" than just using proper query strings; it's more long-winded; irrelevant to Google (which the clean URL craze is passeewise about). -- If you feel like it, you'd need to manually assemble the target path on form submits per JavaScript / or implement a redirect to the supposed cleaner URLs in PHP.

Comment: Relevantly related: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error_pages/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /example.com/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rewrite-php-page\.php\?firstquery=([^\s&]+)&get-input-query=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ rewrite-php-page-%1-get-input-query-%2/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rewrite-php-page\.php\s
RewriteRule ^ rewrite-php-page/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^rewrite-php-page/?$ rewrite-php-page.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^rewrite-php-page-([^-]*)-get-input-query-([^/-]*)/?$ rewrite-php-page.php?firstquery=$1&get-input-query=$2&submit=Send+values [L,QSA,NC]

Rewriterule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap-xml.php [L,NC]
```

- You need to place this in `/example.com/.htaccess` file.
- Better to turn off `MultiViews` options to avoid content negotiation overriding `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: still it doesn't redirect the url properly. when I press a submit a button it display like this http://www.example.com/rewrite-php-page.php?firstquery=111&get-input-query=222&submit=Send+values

Comment: when I use `RewriteBase /` in .htaccess file `localhost/example.com/sitemap.xml` sitemap.xml file doesn't open. but, when I remove `RewriteBase /` from .htaccess file it works. why?

Comment: example.com is my main folder name. all php files and css,js,images folders are under example.com folder. .htaccess, robots.txt are also inside the folder

Comment: it works now. how to add a slash (/) after `get-input-query-456` http://www.example.com/rewrite-php-page-123-get-input-query-456